# How to achieve list.list to list copy in smooks

Tags: java, list, smooks

I'm a beginner in smooks. I'm facing an issue. This is java-java transformation. I have a list and within that I have an inner list with 2 objects. How can I achieve list.list to list copy in smooks?

Comment: @JB. Thanks I was not able to create a tag so added under java

Comment: How about adding an example of what you have tried, and why you are trying to do it, then those trying to answer have somewhere to start

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell `smooks` does not have a method that provides this. You can, however, achieve this by iterating over the lists and extracting the contents out into a new list.

You can define a function to do this, for example:

```
    public List<Object> extractEmbeddedList(List<List<Object>> embeddedList)
    {
        List<Object> extractedList = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (List<Object> l : embeddedList) {
            for (Object o : l) {
                extractedList.add(o);
            }
        }
        return extractedList;
    }
```

Here is an example of it being used:

```
    List<List<Object>> embeddedList = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
    List<Object> someEmbeddedObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<Object> moreEmbeddedObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<Object> normalList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    someEmbeddedObjects.add("I'm a String!");
    someEmbeddedObjects.add("I'm another String!");

    moreEmbeddedObjects.add(5);
    moreEmbeddedObjects.add(6);

    embeddedList.add(someEmbeddedObjects);
    embeddedList.add(moreEmbeddedObjects);

    normalList = extractEmbeddedList(embeddedList);

    System.out.println(normalList.toString());
    //Output is: [I'm a String!, I'm another String!, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Using google's guava library, this is merely Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.concat(embeddedList))

Comment: Or that works too :) If you don't use Google's guava library than the code achieves the same result